# Debugging within a namespace

Tags: r, debugging

I frequently need to debug a function in one of my R packages, and find it convenient to add test code and `print` statements throughout the code.   Then the function is a `method` inside a package, running tests from the console will use the package-stored old version of the function and not the new test version.  I often resort to something like `cat *.r > /tmp/package.r` and then `source('/tmp/package.r')` to override all functions, which allows the test function to be prioritized.  But this doesn't work when I have `.Fortran` or similar calls within the package.

Is there an elegant way to debug with function overrides within the correct version of a local package?

Comment: Before anything about `Fortran` or compiled code checkout [debugging with Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) (mostly the Rstudio part is for visual, it works in base R too). It is the way to go when debugging code rather than printing information. As for compiled code, this will be system dependent. If you're on MacOS or Linux you'll be in luck! You can debug C and C++ code, by recompiling the package and adding some breakpoints (similar to above). If you're on windows, and you find a method for running compiled debuggers with R call me ;-)

Comment: Thanks.   I'm not debugging Fortran or C code but R code that surrounds it.  Does debugging with Rstudio allow me to make and respect code changes from within the package's namespace?

Comment: I'll add a small example to illustrate. The long and short is "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension of my comment above. As said in the comment checkout [this guide](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) for more detail.

To inspect calls dynamically during calls, editing functions and adding code can be done using the `trace(func, edit = TRUE)` method. However it is not the recommended methodology for doing so in any programming language. It is however recommended to instead perform *debugging*. Luckily debugging in R is simpler than many other languages. Some of the most noticeable methods for debugging in R is obtained using

- `debug(func)` or `debugonce(func)`
- `trace`
- `browser`

I'll ignore `trace`'s main usage, and only pass over it briefly in conjunction with `browser`.

Take this small example code

```
x <- 3
f <- function(x){
   x <- x ** 2
   x
}
```

Now if we wanted to "go into" this function and inspect what happens we can use the `debug` method simply by doing

```
debug(f) # alt: debugonce(f)
f(x)
```

and the following shows in the console

```
debugging in: f(x)
debug at #1: {
    x <- x^2
    x
}
```

We see 2 things: The original call in line 1, the function debugged including a function-line-number (#1) with the body in the function (potentially truncated). In addition the command has changed to `Browse[n]` (where n is a number), indicating we are in the **debugger**.

At this point nothing has run so in the "environment" tab in Rstudio we can see `x | x`. Note that `x` is still a **promise** (its value is delayed until used or changed). If we execute `x` we get the value `[1] 3` and we see the environment change to `x | 3` (it has been forced, and is no longer a **promise**).

Inside the debugger we can use the following commands to "walk through" the function

1. `n` to move to the "next line"
2. `s` to move to the "next line", or if the current call is a function, "step" into the function (debug this function)
3. `f` to move forward until the next break (with the added utility that if you are in a loop you stop at "loop end".
4. `c` to move until next break point or end of function (without breaking at end of loops).
5. `Q` to exit immediately

It you click `n` for example you will see

```
debug at #2: x <- x^2
```

printed in the console. This indicates the line that is ***executed next***. Notice the value of `x` in the environment and run `n` again, notice the value changed from `x | 3` to `x | 9` and

```
debug at #3: x
```

is printed. This being the last line pressing `n` again will exit the function and print

```
exiting from: f(x)
[1] 9
```

Once you're done debugging you can run `undebug(f)` to remove the breakpoint and stop the debugger from activating.

This is a simple function, easy to debug, but the idea for more complex functions are the same. If you are in a long loop you can use `f` to skip to the end of the loop, similar to pressing `n` a bunch of times. Note that if you hit an error at any point it will exit automatically when the error occurs and you'll have to walk back to the point again or alternatively use `browser`.

In the case where you have a function like

```
f2 <- function(x){
  x <- x + 2
  f(x)
}
```

you can further **step** into the nested function call `f(x)` by using the `s` command while the line is printing

```
debug at #3: f(x)
```

or by using `debug(f2)` and `debug(f)` in conjunction. Both will give the same result (try it out!).

Now in many cases you might hit a bug or debug many lines (potentially thousands). In this case, you might have some "idea" where you want to start, and this might not be the start of the function. In this case you can use `browser()`. This basically sets a **breakpoint**. Whenever `browser()` is hit, it will **stop** and start the debugger (similar to `debug(f)` and calling `f(x)` but at a specific point). Try for example

```
f3 <- function(x){
  x1 <- f(x)
  browser()
  x2 <- f2(x)
  c(x1, x2)
}
f3(x)
```

and you'll notice see

```
Called from: f3(x)
```

printed (if you have run `undebug(f2)` and `undebug(f)` first).

Lets say it is not your function but a function within a namespace, well then we can even add the breakpoint ourself at run-time. Try for example calling

```
trace(f3, edit = TRUE)
```

and you will see an editing window pop up. Simply add `browser()` at the desired spot and click **save**. This edits the function within the namespace. It will be reverted once R is closed or alternatively you can remove it with another call to `trace(f3, edit = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Sirius answer to use `devtools::load` is the most direct answer to my question.  But all of the answers are exceptionally helpful and I will use all of them. I wish the system let me check multiple "most helpful" answers.   Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of your IDE, you can reload your package under development with devtools:

```r
devtools::load_all("path/to/your/package/directory")
```

This should load it to your R session (RStudio has buttons and keyboard shortcuts for this too)